# Laravel real time Highcharts

Tags: php, laravel, highcharts, real-time, pusher

i'm currently using laravel 5.4 with highcharts to display some data from my mysql database. That's working fine.

I need to have one chart display real time data, any ideas on the best way to do this?

Would something like Pusher be appropriate or is it overkill?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you mean as "real time". When all 10 seconds is okay, you can simply do it with an ajax loop. But if you want to tigger it right now after a value has changed, pusher should be the better solution.

For the pusher case you could use any simple pusher example with larave, e.g. the one from their official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting).

Comment: Ok. I worded it incorrectly. One chart needs to fetch data every 15 seconds, so ajax long poll for this?

Comment: Maybe, but implementing an event with broadcast with pusher is always the best solution, if you want to update the client when some data changed in Laravel.

Comment: I'd concur with @mimo on this. Long polling isn't terribly efficient compared to Websockets, and it's not truly realtime. The only time I would consider long polling for this is if for some reason Websockets wasn't possible, such as a company intranet where all the users were using an old version of IE that didn't support Websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Either Pusher or the Redis broadcasting driver will do fine for this use case. Pusher is probably easier if you haven't done something like this before.

Essentially you'd just broadcast an event when the data changes and include the data in that event, then listen for that event on the client and use the data to update the application state.